# Does it make a difference between using two if's in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

Is there any difference between

```
if (firstCheck())
    return;

if (secondCheck())
    return;
```

and

```
if (firstCheck() || secondCheck())
    return;
```

?

The focus of my question is on the runtime!

Comment: Not sure how this is "primarily opinion-based". The question if the compiler will generate different code where one is more efficient than the other is a simple yes/no question that can definitely be answered.

Comment: No both approaches are equal.

Comment: really no offense, but imho it is bad practice to worry about such micro  optimizations rather than readability. Write code to be readable and let the compiler do its job ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there will be no difference. An optimizing compiler should generate the same binary.

There is no way to say that one is better than the other. If the two conditions are closely related, I would write them in one `if` clause, if they are independent, I would use two.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming regular cases, both are similar.

For tricky/evil cases, where `firstCheck()`/`secondCheck()` return custom type, with overloaded `operator ||`, they are different.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is called "shortcircuiting". The built-in `operator||` for booleans will only evaluate the second argument if the first argument is `false`.

Comment: So the second one is faster in average (depending on how often the firste argument will be false)?

Comment: @monamona with gcc 7.2 and optimization, generated code is same : https://godbolt.org/g/5zaEq3

Comment: And without optimization, two `if` generates a shorter code with gcc 7.2 : https://godbolt.org/g/4taFs7 (only true for this compiler, you have to check for other)

Comment: @monamona: No - in the first example, `secondCheck` is also evaluated only when `firstCheck` is false, but in the first example that's because the body of the first `if` statement contains a `return`.